Formatting display of cell references in formulas (when using F2)
In Excel, how to control formatting of the display of cell references in formulas (when using F2) – particularly the font size? In some cases, text referencing a cell within a formula takes on a small font size. How do I control this?


Tried many methods to reproduce in MS Excel 365 (app and webview) and could not. What version/platform is this?

@usncahill  MS Excel 365 in app. I observe the display behavior sporadically and haven’t noted a trend or influence. I don’t believe this display behavior is associated with certain workbooks, but am investigating further. Any ideas where the behavior could be controlled by selection of properties?

I saw this momentarily yesterday, so I now know what you are talking about. Mine presented as giant A2 references while the remaining formula text was normal. I think I was in the web app when it happened. I had not changed any settings or options. It is definitely sporatic.
